# Can i add azure database for free to sharepoint hosted app on office 365

Tags: office-365

Is there any way I can add azure database to sharepoint hosted app for free if not then paid ?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695161/Walkthrough-Creating-a-O-SharePoint-App-wi

This project seems like embedding database into application, please tell me how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need to use Auto-Hosted (free azure storage) or Provider-Hosted (you are resp for creating the whole web application including storage).

Comment: oh so with auto-hosted, I get free database on azure sql ?

Comment: Yepp! Thats right

Comment: oh my dayssssssssss, any link to tutorial will help me give you +1 vote as well, thank you

Comment: Please note that auto-hosted apps only are available in Office 365 (SP Online) though

Comment: Basic tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179886(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think auto hosted apps are still in preview state so it is not recommended to use for production scenarios. The option we have now is Provider hosted app.
https://officeams.codeplex.com/discussions/539315

P.S. I can't add as comment due to reputation limit.